# Pipe to exec'ed process

Tags: go, pipe, system-calls

My Go application outputs some amounts of text data and I need to pipe it to some external command (e.g. `less`). I haven't find any way to pipe this data to `syscall.Exec`'ed process.

As a workaround I write that text data to a temporary file and then use that file as an argument to `less`:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    content := []byte("temporary file's content")
    tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "example")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer os.Remove(tmpfile.Name()) // Never going to happen!

    if _, err := tmpfile.Write(content); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := tmpfile.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    binary, err := exec.LookPath("less")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    args := []string{"less", tmpfile.Name()}

    if err := syscall.Exec(binary, args, os.Environ()); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

It works but leaves a temporary file on a file system, because `syscall.Exec` replaces the current Go process with another (`less`) one and deferred `os.Remove` won't run. Such behaviour is not desirable.

Is there any way to pipe some data to an external process without leaving any artefacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`os/exec`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) to build an [`exec.Cmd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) to execute, then you could supply any `io.Reader` you want as the stdin for the command.

From the example in the documentation:

```
cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("some input")
var out bytes.Buffer
cmd.Stdout = &out
err := cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("in all caps: %q\n", out.String())
```

If you want to write directly to the command's stdin, then you call [`cmd.StdInPipe`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdinPipe) to get an `io.WriteCloser` you can write to.

If you really need to `exec` the process in place of your current one, you can simply remove the file before exec'ing, and provide that file descriptor as stdin for the program.

```
content := []byte("temporary file's content")
tmpfile, err := ioutil.TempFile("", "example")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
os.Remove(tmpfile.Name())

if _, err := tmpfile.Write(content); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

tmpfile.Seek(0, 0)

err = syscall.Dup2(int(tmpfile.Fd()), syscall.Stdin)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

binary, err := exec.LookPath("less")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

args := []string{"less"}

if err := syscall.Exec(binary, args, os.Environ()); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of `os/exec` *et al*, but it won't solve my problem at all. I want to pipe data to pager-like environment (`less`), not to process it with some text utilities and deal with the output.

Comment: @PetrShevtsov: I misunderstood, because you can't directly pipe to a process you're going to exec. A pipe is blocking and the data has to be buffered somewhere. It's not a Go problem per say, because you can't do that in general. If you're on a posix system (which I assume with the syscall.Exec and `less` calls), you can just remove the tmp file.

Comment: thank you, it works! But can I get rid of temp file and write directly to `syscall.Stdin`?

Comment: @PetrShevtsov: no, for the reason I stated earlier, the data needs to be buffered somewhere and your original process no longer exists to write to the stdin after the Exec call. Some programs may do this by forking too, and having the child continue to write to FD 0, but you can't fork in Go.